# Webpack mini-css-extract-plugin breaks popup js on my chrome extension

Tags: webpack, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm working on a chrome extension project.
I'm using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to inject CSS into the `content` script.
It's working perfectly fine actually, but it breaks popup.js now.
It seems that can't access my popup.js

```
Your file couldn’t be accessed. It may have been moved, edited, or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

The only thing I did was add the below.

```js
// craco.config.js
webpack: {
  configure: (webpackConfig, {env, paths}) => {
    return {
      ...
      plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "[name].css" })], //this is added
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// manifest.json
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": ["./main.css"], // this is added
      ...
```

And this is the `mini-css-extract-plugin` version I'm using.
`"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",`

If anybody have similar experience, please left some comments.

Thanks